# incorrect visible view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, navigationcontroller

I am trying to call a segue in my iOS app but am getting the error

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue ___
```

I determined that the issue is that when I try to check the current visibleViewController, it is not the ViewController that the segue is linked to:

```
if(self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self){
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}else{
        NSLog(@"LoginViewController is not currently visible");            
}
```

**My question is, how can I set the correct view controller so I can call the segue?**

Here is all my code:

**LoginViewController:** (The first ViewController)

```
-(IBAction)registerClick:(id)sender{
    // open up registration
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"registration" sender:self];
}
```

**Registration ViewController** (the Modal ViewController)

```
-(IBAction)finish:(id)sender{
    // return back to login view controller
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**LoginViewController segue attempt**:

```
    if(self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self){
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}else{
        NSLog(@"LoginViewController is not currently visible");            
}
```

Comment: I would guess the "login_success" identifier is unknown to `self`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is.  My LoginViewController is calling a modal, which is then dismissed to return back to LoginViewController.  Then why I try to use a segue, I get the error.

Comment: for clarification - if I don't call the modal, the segue works fine.

Comment: you can do the perform segue and then dismiss that view controller you presented modally, should be okay.

Comment: @sunshine - that's what I have I believe and it's not working. I added all my code above.

Comment: I don't see  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]`

Comment: Are you sure the `login_success` segue is called after the modal view controller has been dismissed?